# Creating a dictionary from a list of lists using a second list as keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of column names, and a list of lists that I would like to turn into a nested dictionary, where each inner list contains the column names as keys. By applying the code below, I encounter the same problem as my real data - I get the right key:value pairs, but only for the very last list.

I thought the way I was trying was a pretty simple approach (too simple?). I'm open to any way to do this, preferably without the use of third party packages, but in the interest of learning would like to know why this doesn't work.

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
list_of_lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]

for x in list_of_lists:
    test = dict(zip(keys, x))

print(test)
```

Desired output:

```
{{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}}
```

Actual output:

```
{1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}
```

Comment: You are over-writing `test`...

Comment: It looks like you want a list of dictionaries and not a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Python: it has two dictionaries, which are mutable and non-hashable structures, inside a set, which requires immutable, hashable values. Do you want that outer structure to be a list?

Comment: Please clarify the expected output.

Comment: Your desired output is a set of dicts, that’s not possible

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim, actually it is currently a set of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the output.  You're all right -  I do want a list of dictionaries. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is indeed a **list** of dicts, a very simple one-liner:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
list_of_lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]

print([dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in list_of_lists])
# [{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
list_of_lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
test = []

for x in list_of_lists:
    test.append(dict(zip(keys, x)))

print(test)
```

This gives the list of dictionaries.

Output:

```
[{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}]
```

Nested dictionaries would require you to have key for each inner element. In the below example, I'm using count as key.

```
keys = [1, 2, 3]
list_of_lists = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
test = {}
count = 0

for x in list_of_lists:
    test[count] = dict(zip(keys, x))
    count = count + 1

print(test)
```

Output:

```
{0: {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, 1: {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you’re desired output shows is a set of dicts, and with a dict being unhashable this will not work.

Alternatively you could make a list or tuple of dicts:

```
test = [{k:v for k, v in zip(keys, l)} for l in list_of_lists]
#[{1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}]
```

Or a dict of dicts, the keys for the outer dict being an enumeration of the outer list

```
test = {i: {k:v for k, v in zip(keys, l)} for i, l in enumerate(list_of_lists)}
#{0: {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'}, 1: {1: 'D', 2: 'E', 3: 'F'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better off placing your dictionaries in a list.

```
[dict(zip(keys, x)) for x in list_of_lists]
```

I am not sure, perhaps you would be interested in the order and then you might want to try

```
{i:x for i, x in zip(range(len(list_of_lists)), list_of_lists)}
```

Hope this helps

Edit:
Changed the dictionary response code

Comment: No keys? That's not even a dictionary; it is a set holding dictionaries.

Comment: Ahhh, yes. My apologies.

Comment: `{i:x for dict(zip(keys, x)) for i, x in zip(range(len(list_of_lists), list_of_lists)}` is not a valid syntax